# Problems with \sum lower limit when in an exponent (displayed maths)

Tags: equations, delimiters

I just can't get the lower limit to be **under** the `$\Sigma $` in an equation that has this:

```
\begin{align*}
 e^{ - \sum_{x_n \leq t}{g(x_n)} 
\end{align*}
```

I've tried `\[ \]` ,the  `align*` environment; and nothing...

Comment: `\limits`  should help, I think. Welcome to TeX.SX

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, it was helpful, indeed, thank you!..now the problem is that the lower limit is too big , and `\small` doesn't work!

Comment: Perhaps consider using `\exp`  instead of a superscripted `e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this? The sum in the exponent looks a little bit too much, but perphaps this is necessary this way.

`\limits` is meant for providing the limits for a `\sum`, `\int` or `\prod` operator, having the syntax `\sum\limits_{lower}^{upper}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 e^{ - \sum\limits_{x_n \leq t}g(x_n)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! I had just found `\limits`, and it helps! Thank you! Now the problem is the lower limit is relatively too big, and `\small ` doesn´t work!

Comment: @Max -- actually, the size of the lower limit is "correct".  the problem is, this is the smallest size available; the sum, *g* and *x* are `\scriptsize`, the subscript to the "main" *x* and the *x* and *t* in the lower limit are `\scriptscriptsize`, and tex doesn't define anything smaller, so the subscript *n* in the limit is the same size as what it's subscripting.  this is one of the reasons that it's recommended to use the `\exp` notation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Are, you're quicker in the explanation. There's not much that can be done. Perhaps writing the whole stuff as product would be better?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, I'll change my notation to `\exp` ; since it's necessary  (because of the context) to write it like that, rather than as a product. Thank you both.